# Angular flex-layout wrong overflow

Tags: javascript, css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I want to use Angular's flexLayout. Problem is, when I try to overflow flexible content, it wont be. When content is larger than its container, it simply "overgrow" it's container.

I have found solition, but [Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing](https://caniuse.com/#search=Intrinsic%20%26%20Extrinsic%20Sizing) suport is poor at this moment.

Here is an plunker [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1vR9Ok3HwBgc5iO9rrif?p=preview). I have tried `min-height` prop:

```
.detail-row-item{
  // min-height: min-content; //good solution, but poor browser suport
}
```

It worked on chrome. Is there any different solution to do `min-height: min-content;` result ?

Edit:
I found out that this example, works fine on Firefox and Edge only chrome has problem as shown on screenshot.
[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restrict the height of the `div` elements and their content overflows their size, you can use the CSS [overflow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to adjust the behavior. So if you add `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden;` to your `.card-wrapper` class definition, the cards will get scrollbars or just hide the overflowing texts.

Edit:

To achieve the same result as with `min-height: min-content`, just remove the flex attribute of the `div.detail-content-wrapper` element and set the following ones:

```
.detail-content-wrapper {
  max-height: 50%; 
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You can check the [modified plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ICbP9FngFBjJfWy1mgc6?p=preview).

Comment: I don't want to restrict sizes or overflow each card-wrapper. I just want the same result as i wrote

Answer (score -1):

Add like this below in your CSS file.

```
    .card-wrapper.detail-card {
    overflow: auto;
}
```